# How to `postForm` with header

Tags: r, rcurl

How to construct this `POST` http request using `RCurl`?

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "name" : "node_auto_index",
  "config" : {
    "type" : "fulltext",
    "provider" : "lucene"
  }
}
```

I've come up with this in `R`:

```
require(RCurl)
httpheader=c(Accept="application/json; charset=UTF-8",
             "Content-Type"="application/json")
x = postForm("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/",
             .opts=list(httpheader=httpheader),
             name="node_auto_index",
             config=c(type="fulltext", provider="lucene")
)
```

Is this statement correct?

Comment: Does it work? I'm guessing not. Seems like the you would need to build the json body yourself and set `style="POST"` so you don't get name/value pairs in the body. Can you intercept the request to see what's being sent?

Comment: I can try building the JSON body with RJSONIO::toJSON, however where to pass it? How can I intercept the request to get the instant feedback what's being sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little easier with httr:

```
library(httr)
POST("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/",
  accept_json(),
  add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
  body = toJSON(list(
    "name" = "node_auto_index",
    "config" = list(
      "type" = "fulltext",
      "provider" = "lucene"
    )
  ))
)
```

It's even easier with the dev version (`install_github("hadley/devtools")`:

```
POST("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/",
  accept_json(),
  body = list(
    "name" = "node_auto_index",
    "config" = list(
      "type" = "fulltext",
      "provider" = "lucene"
    )
  ),
  encode = "json"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you need a call more like this

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)

jsonbody <- toJSON(list(name="node_auto_index", 
    config=list(type="fulltext",provider="lucene")))

httpheader <- c(Accept="application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Type"="application/json")
x <- postForm("http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/",
    .opts=list(httpheader=httpheader,
    postfields=jsonbody))
```

or even

```
h <- basicTextGatherer()
x <- curlPerform(url="http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/",
    httpheader=c(Accept="application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Type"="application/json"),
    writefunction = h$update,
    postfields=jsonbody)
```

As far as I know the RCurl library won't make JSON for you, so you need to build the JSON yourself (here using the RJSONIO package). Here we pass the data using the `postfields` option.

Also, the website http://requestb.in/ can be useful to create a URL where you can post data and see the request for testing

Comment: You'll want a `writefunction` if you use the `curlPerform` version.

Comment: @Thomas Is that better? Maybe I should leave out `curlPerfom` (unless there's a way to make a nice JSON writer or something)

Comment: It's more complete, which is good. You could also show the `httr::POST` solution, which will infer the content is JSON and convert it automatically with `content`. The basic call isn't any cleaner than what you have for `postForm`, though.

Comment: How can I view/verify syntax of the request that `postForm` ultimately sent?

Comment: @DanielKrizian That's there the http://requestb.in/ website comes it. It creates  URL that you can post to and then on the website you can see what requests are sent. Or you could use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to intercept web requests and view them.

Comment: Ah I see. So when sent to `requestb.in`, I see the possibly redundant `Connection: close` line in the header that I didn't specify - maybe a reason my real request is being rejected. How to remove that from theheader? Possibly this is some default parameter within `RCurl`

Comment: @DanielKrizian In `curlPerform`, you can use `headerfunction` and/or the `verbose` option to get more details about what's going on.

Comment: @DanielKrizian It seems unlikely that the the "connection: close" would make much of a difference. What make you believe your request isn't working. Are you getting an error? Just an empty response?

Comment: I am getting `Error: Bad Request` response instead of the [response as specified here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/). The answer and discussion clears many things up though so it's worth accepting. Thank you again