# Using RCurl postForm to gather JSON data

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I am trying to extract time series data from the [BLS API](http://www.bls.gov/developers/) using `RCurl`.

The BLS supplies the following sample code for command line extraction:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     -d '{"seriesid":["LEU0254555900", "APU0000701111"],
        "startyear":"2002", "endyear":"2012"}' 
        http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/
```

I have also confirmed that the specified files (i.e. series ids) are both present as the following both yield a JSON formatted object:

```
require(RCurl)
bls.content_test1 <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/LEU0254555900")
bls.content_test2 <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/APU0000701111")
```

Based on a variety of posts with the `RCurl` tag (and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387119/how-to-postform-with-header) in particular), I have ported the command line script to the following chunk of code:

```
require(RJSONIO)

jsonbody <- toJSON(list("seriesid"=paste('"["CFU0000008000"', '[LEU0254555900"]"')
                        ,"startyear"="2012"
                        ,"endyear"="2013"))

httpheader <- c(Accept="application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                "Content-Type"="application/json")

bls.content <- postForm("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/"
                        ,.opts=list(httpheader=httpheader
                                    ,postfields=jsonbody))
```

Which yields:

```
[1] "{\"status\":\"REQUEST_FAILED\",\"responseTime\":0,\"message\":[\"Your request has failed, please check your input parameters and try your request again.\"],\"Results\":null}"
attr(,"Content-Type")
                              charset 
"application/json"            "UTF-8"
```

Does this appear to be a problem with my implementation of `RCurl` or does this appear to be a problem with the BLS API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a problem with the way you are creating your `json` body. With your version if you do `cat(jsonbody)` you get

```
{
 "seriesid": "\"[\"CFU0000008000\" [LEU0254555900\"]\"",
"startyear": "2012",
"endyear": "2013"
}
```

which has those extra escapes and brackets in there. It's not correct. Instead try

```
jsonbody <- toJSON(list("seriesid"=c("CFU0000008000", "LEU0254555900"),
                        startyear="2012",
                        endyear="2013"))
```

which gives

```
{
 "seriesid": [ "CFU0000008000", "LEU0254555900" ],
"startyear": "2012",
"endyear": "2013" 
}
```

which is valid JSON. Just changing that part and using the rest of the code as you had it gives me a REQUEST_SUCCEEDED message.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with httr:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Need unbox() to tell jsonlite() numbers are scalars, not vectors of length 1
body <- list(
  seriesid = c("CFU0000008000", "LEU0254555900"),
  startyear = unbox(2012),
  endyear = unbox(2013)
)

r <- POST("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/", body = body, encode = "json")
stop_for_status(r)

# Need to specify type since site returns incorrect type of text/plain
str(content(r, type = "application/json"))
```